# View JSON key value

Tags: json, node.js

So this is my first time using nodeJs and first exposure to APIs in general. I am trying to get the value for a certain key from JSON that I receive in a response.

Here is a sample: 
[image: JSON example]

I need the value of name, which in this case would be "Hillary_Clinton".
But when I do

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).face_detection.name);
```

it returns undefined. I tried it with .confidence , .quality etc. but they all return undefined. If I do just .face_detection , it properly returns everything inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`face_detection` is an array not an object.

try `console.log(JSON.parse(body).face_detection[0].name);`

Comment: Oh wow now I feel dumb. Thanks so much! I cant mark your answer yet as I have to wait out the time limit set by SO

Answer (score 1):

```
 JSON.parse(body).face_detection[0].name
```

When the console work doesn´t work, try to do:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body) ,JSON.parse(body).face_detection , JSON.parse(body).face_detection.name);
```

This way, you can see what is the first object that you can´t have access. And see their structure.